# Jenkins Amazon ECR Plugin login issue "Authorization Token has expired"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, amazon-ecr

I've followed the instructions on the Amazon ECR Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+ECR, which simply instructs a user to install the Amazon ECR configure the Docker Build & Deploy plugin), but Jenkins is unable to authenticate with ECR.

The error message produced is:

```
denied: Your Authorization Token has expired. Please run 'aws ecr get-login' to fetch a new one.
```

Any advice anyone can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue - did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I always use this command as the first step in my Jenkins jobs for login to ECR:

```
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --profile ecr | bash
```

where "--profile ecr" is predefined profile in Jenkins (.asw/config, .aws/credentials)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the variable `env.AWS_ECR_LOGIN=true` in your pipeline, the issue is resolved. It is something on the `docker.withregistry` step:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44143